# call a jquery function on window width below 468px

Tags: jquery

I have the a jquery code to fix a div at the bottom of the page when scrolling.

```
var ad = jQuery('.top_leaderboard_container');
var min_scroll = 25; // Set your minimum scroll amount here
jQuery(window).scroll(
    function() {
        var t = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        if (t > min_scroll) {
            // define your scroll CSS here

            ad.css({position: "fixed" , bottom:"0"});
        } else {
            // define your non-scrolled CSS here

            ad.css({position: "relative"});
        }
    }
);
```

I want that this function to be happened only when the width of the website is below 468px .
What jquery code i have to add for achieving this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
// call your code on page load
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    widthSmallerThan(468);
});

// call it every time the window size changes and is smaller than...
jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    widthSmallerThan(468);
});

var widthSmallerThan = function(width) {
    if (jQuery(window).width() < width) {
        // your code
    }
};
```

Comment: one more thing i want to ask that what should i do if i have to add z-index on my div class which i want to fix at bottom ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(window).width() < 468) {

    // your logic here

}
```

This will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can use media-query available in CSS3.

```
@media (max-width: 468px) {
  .top_leaderboard_container{position: "relative";}
}

@media (min-width: 469px) {
   .top_leaderboard_container{position: "fixed"; bottom:"0";}
}
```

More Information click [here](http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/).